# How to return the max number of consecutive dot occurrence in a string?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

When parsing a string, we always use `StringTokenizer` or the `split` method to parse a string by:
,
or
.
or
:

and so on,

My problem is I have a text file that has characters and dots like this :
cta...cc.tt..at
ta.....tct.c.t.

My problem is to parse this text file and return the max number of occurence of dots, for example the above text file should return : 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on ct_'s original answer, if the file is not too big you can load it as a string and have `String.split` extract the dots by splitting on every string of non-dots, i.e., `[^.]+`.

```
"cta...cc.tt..at ta.....tct.c.t.".split("[^.]+") =>
   { "", "...", ".", "..", ".....", ".", ".", "." }
```

Then it is trivial to get the length of the longest string.

```
int longestCount = 0;
for (String dots : text.split("[^.]+")) {
    if (dots.length() > longestCount) {
        longestCount = dots.length();
    }
}
```

Comment: Much nicer than my attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Use the regular expression pattern `"(\\.+)"` and then you can inspect the length of the captured group.

Look at the Java regex documentation for `java.util.regex.Pattern` and `Matcher`.

Comment: Yes, I know this is vague, but it looks like homework, so this is a homework-level answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use String.split rather than a StringTokenizer (it's deprecated) and provide a regular expression that matches one or more dots.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Comment: You would actually want to match on everything that's not a dot to produce an array of strings containing dots.

Comment: Good point - answer edited